# Crear formulario a medida y cargar modal - SDK PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap, formularios, mercadopago

Estoy integrando el SDK de PHP de Mercadopago en una pagina simple
El usuario debe cargar nombre, dni, etc. y luego al enviar los datos se deberia cargar el modal de Mercadopago, de la misma manera en que está hecho este ejemplo que encontré:

http://www.estudiodedivorcios.com.ar/mercadopago/

Ya he realizado el formulario, etc. pero al recibir el $_POST como deberia hacer para cargar los datos ingresados y enviarlos al modal de Mercadopago?

Gracias

Comment: Comparte el código con el que estás trabajando para que podamos encontrar el error

Comment: @federhico ya lo solucione, debia utilizar render.js y mandarle parametros utilizando la inicializacion de preferencias de pago en create_preference

Answer (score 1):

Bueno por lo que compendo simplemente tienes unos datos y necesitan reenviarlos a otra url para eso puedes realizar lo siguiente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Redireccionado</title>
</head>
<body>

   <p>Descripction para el usuario</p> 

   <form action="ruta de Mercadopago" id="formulario">
     
     <input type="hiden" name="nombreVariable">
     <input type="hiden" name="nombreVariable">
     <input type="hiden" name="nombreVariable">
     <input type="hiden" name="nombreVariable">
     <input type="hiden" name="nombreVariable">
  <input type="submit" value="Continuar"/>
   </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
// enviar formulario
 document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado Carlos. Gracias